# Use Salesforce CLI To Retrieve object action

Tags: cli, custom-actions

In my dev org I have a custom action on an object. I want to use the Salesforce CLI get pull the custom action to my local machine. The action type is Lightning Component if that makes any difference.

I figured it would be something like:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ?????:My_Custom_Action
```

Comment: Can you try `LightningComponentBundle`?

Comment: @JefersonChaves that is one of the things I tried before posting my question. I get an error "Entity of type 'LightningComponentBundle' named 'My_Custom_Action' cannot be found". Sorry, should have mentioned that I tried that.

Comment: Fair enough James, I think Alex has probably answered your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify object API Name, e.g.:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m QuickAction:Account.My_Custom_Action
```